# MFC ComboBox keeps the list void after deleting its items

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a MFC ComboBox with some items as shown below:

[image: ComboBox with items]

When I delete the items with the following code:

```
void CComboBoxTestDlg::OnBnClickedButtonClear()
{        
        CComboBox *pCmb = (CComboBox *)GetDlgItem(IDC_COMBO);
         pCmb->ResetContent();
}
```

It deletes the strings inside the ComboBox but it keeps the list void with the same height as if it had items inside as shown below:

[image: ComboBox after deleting its content]

I tried also this code:

```
for (int i = pCmb->GetCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--)  
        pCmb->DeleteString(i);
```

and also deletes the items inside, but it keeps the undesired list void.

Is there any way to delete the contents of the ComboBox without keeping the remaining void list?

Comment: And how do you want to look the combobox list when doesn't contain any item ?

Comment: @flaviu2 The ComboBox needs to be updated dynamically and also must have the capability of being clear. Initially it has no item, and if the user clicks "Clear" it should clear all it items.
Yes, there is useless to click the ComboBox after clicking "Clear" but if the user clicks it, it will see that long void (and meaningless) list. 

Is it the default behavior or I'm doing something wrong? I just want to reset to the initial state without any item or list.

Comment: @manujcm you aren't doing anything wrong. That's the default (and questionable) behaviour of a combobox.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks. I see. So basically I'll need to modify the default behavior by myself if I want to avoid it. The problem is that I don't have a where to start. :-( Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

When the number of items in the drop down list becomes zero, call this:

```
CRect rect;
pCmb->GetClientRect(&rect);
pCmb->SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, rect.Width(), rect.Height() + 1, SWP_NOMOVE);
```

Now the drop down box has a minimal height.

When the number of items in the drop down list non zero (that is as soon as you add an item), call this:

```
CRect rect;
pCmb->GetClientRect(&rect);
pCmb->SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, rect.Width(), rect.Height() * N, SWP_NOMOVE);
```

where `N` is the desired maximum height in lines of the dropdown box of the combobox.

Comment: I clicked both accept the answer and upvote but it says "Once you have 15 of reputation, your vote will change the publicly displayed post score". I hope at least the answer is considered as accepted in spite of my low reputation.